# Scripting to automate projects with microchip tools

Tags: c, microcontroller, microchip

- IDE: MPLAB IDE 8.87
- Compilers: C30/ASM30
- Debugger/Programmer: MPLAB ICD 3
- Windows 7

**Question:** I have utility projects such as clearing an EEPROM on custom hardware, retrieve data from an IC, and so on. I would like to be able to automate the procedure for such tasks.

Example: Clear EEPROM.

- Input to script: Start location, number of bytes, EEPROM physical Address
- Output from script: Selected range deleted successfully/Failed

The steps for this will be to build and link project with the input information, program the uController connected to the debugger, execute code, validate for successful completion and inform the user of the outcome.

**How can I write scripts like this?**

I have no experience of previous scripting, and this question is motivated simply to avoid wasting time in the future.

Kind Regards,

Comment: My apologize I thought I was asking on Electronics section, I will also leave this question here just in case I can get an answer here too.

Comment: [Link to the electronics post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104280/scripting-to-automate-projects-with-microchip-tools) for reference.

Comment: This question has been answered at: 

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104280/scripting-to-automate-projects-with-microchip-tools